# provides and inject two instances with different implementations - Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a situation where I need two Retrofit Services, each one has its business implementation.

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("defaultMulhimService")
    MulhimService provideMulhimService() {
        return MulhimService.Creator.newMulhimService();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("MulhimServiceWithCache")
    MulhimService providesMulhimServiceWithCache(){
        return MulhimService.Creator.newMulhimServiceWithCache(mApplication);
    }
```

I'm already looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883655/dagger-2-injecting-multiple-instances-of-same-object-type) which suggest using @Named annotation to differ multiple instances at modules, but what I don't know, how to inject them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this (https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) -

```
@Provides @Named("cached")
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setCache(cache);
    return client;
}

@Provides @Named("non_cached") @Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    return client;
}

@Inject @Named("cached") OkHttpClient client;
@Inject @Named("non_cached") OkHttpClient client2;
```

Basically you inject the instance using the @Named qualifier

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Yes, just annotate the parameter instead.